# What happens if you write a variable name alone in python?

Tags: python, lighttable

Recently I became curious about but what happens in line 2 of the following bogus python code:

```
def my_fun(foo,bar):
    foo
    return foo + bar
```

The reason I became interested is that I'm trying Light Table and tried to put a watch on "foo." It appeared to cause the python interpreter to hang.

Am I correct in thinking that this line has absolutely no effect and does not cause any sort of error? Can someone explain what the interpreter does exactly here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One can look at what is happening with a little help from the built-in [dis](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
import dis

def my_fun(foo,bar):
    foo
    return foo + bar

dis.dis(my_fun)
```

The `dis.dis` function disassembles functions (yep, it can disassemble itself), methods, and classes.

The output of `dis.dis(my_fun)` is:

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 POP_TOP

  5           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              7 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
             10 BINARY_ADD
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first two bytecodes are exactly what we need: the `foo` line.

Here's what these bytecodes do:

1. The first one pushes a reference to a local variable `foo` onto the stack
   ([LOAD_FAST](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST))
2. The second one removes the top of the stack ([POP_TOP](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-POP_TOP))

Basically, `foo` line has no effect. (well, if `foo` variable is not defined then `LOAD_FAST` will throw the `NameError`)

Answer (score 9):

Nothing happens. It becomes equivalent to a pointless operation
Looking at the `dis` output

```
In [3]: dis.dis(my_fun)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 POP_TOP             

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              7 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
             10 BINARY_ADD          
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can see that it does the load fast for `foo` then does nothing with it.

Comment: + 1, I did not know about `dis`

Answer (score 4):

Try it at the command line: it just returns the value in `foo`. 
This doesn't mean it can't have side effects in some special cases: if you do something like:

```
def my_fun(foo, bar):
    foo.prop
    return foo.func(bar)
```

even though technically we have just returned the value, if it's defined as a property then `foo.prop` can actually call a function.

But normally... you wouldn't do this in modules, only in an interactive console.

Answer (score 2):

The `foo` statement is an example of [expression statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements), so it gets evaluated when the interpreter meets it.

> An expression statement evaluates the expression list (which may be a
>   single expression).

So `foo` is loaded, the expression is evaluated (which is `foo` itself, so no further actions are needed) and the result is forgotten immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens:

```
>>> def baz(foo, bar):
    foo
    return bar

>>> baz(10, 20)
20
```

The statement has no effect.

Comment: Although your conclusion is correct, your argument is bogus. Just because it does nothing in one case that you found, doesn't mean it does nothing in all cases.